# Alternative query for MongoDB aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is the sample data that I am working on:

```javascript
{
    "_id": 1,
    "user": A,
    "nums":[1,2,3,4]
}
{
    "_id": 2,
    "user": B,
    "nums":[1,2,4]
}
{
    "_id": 3,
    "user": B,
    "nums":[4,5,7]
}
```

What I am trying to get is the number of logs for each user and the distinct "nums" list for each user. So the result is something like this:

```javascript
[
    {
        "user": A,
        "total": 1,
        "nums" : [1,2,3,4]
    },
    {
        "user": B,
        "total": 2,
        "nums" : [1,2,4,5,7]
    }
]
```

Is that possible to achieve in one aggregate query? I am now using two.

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([{ $group: { _id:"$user", total:{$sum:1}}}])
db.test.aggregate([{$unwind:"$nums"}, { $group: { _id:"$user", nums:{$addToSet:"$nums"}}}])
```

Also, should one query be faster than two separate queries on large data set or I should just stay with two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by assembling a list of the original `_id` values from the docs in the `$group` after the `$unwind` to provide a way to get the total count in a final `$project`:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$nums'},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$user',
        ids: {$addToSet: '$_id'},
        nums: {$addToSet: '$nums'}
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        user: '$_id',
        total: {$size: '$ids'},
        nums: 1
    }}
])
```

Result:

```javascript
[
  {
    "nums": [
      7,
      5,
      4,
      2,
      1
    ],
    "user": "B",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "nums": [
      4,
      3,
      2,
      1
    ],
    "user": "A",
    "total": 1
  }
]
```

I would expect that doing it all in one `aggregate` pipeline instead of two will be faster, but it's always best to test it in your own environment to be sure.